# Yii: How to add CSS class to a dropdown list

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii 1.1.10. I would like to know how to add a CSS class to a dropdown list.
I am using a CActiveForm

for example, how would i add a CSS class to this dropdown list?

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'chassis'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'chassis',
      array('saloon' => 'saloon', 'station wagon' => 'station wagon', ),
   ); 
?>
```

**EDIT:**
I had this in my code

```
 array('empty' => 'Select one of the following...')
```

i had it there to make it the default message. but somehow it interfered with using

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'yourCssClass')
```

**OR**

```
array('class'=>'your_class_name')
```

so as long as i remove it, both suggestions work!Thank guys

Comment: P.S To use a placeholder use `prompt` instead of `empty`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `htmlOptions` argument of [`CActiveFrom::dropDownList()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#dropDownList-detail) to specify `class`,`style` or any other HTML attributes.

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'chassis'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'chassis',
      array('saloon' => 'saloon', 'station wagon' => 'station wagon', ),
      array('class'=>'your_class_name'),
   ); 
?>
```

Comment: i have tried that but it does not work; i used chrome and inspected the dropdown and no class...what do you suggest..

Comment: you get a class in the select tag. do you want a class on each option tag?

Comment: ok it works. It was working because i had sth. extra added that i left out in my question...ive made an edit in my question so u can see it..@naselorm samething, your suggestion works too thanks guys..

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax for dropDownList according to Yiiframework API

```
public string dropDownList(CModel $model, string $attribute, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

The last part enables you to pass any html values as you would normally do in an html page.Thus add this after station wagon,

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'yourCssClass'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Array values are displayed and array keys are stored.

This is Model code.

```
public function getCityOptions()
{
   $list=array('saloon' => 'saloon', 'station wagon' => 'station wagon',);
   asort($list);
   return $list;
}
```

This the _form.php code

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'chassis'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'chassis',$model->getCityOptions()); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'chassis'); ?>
</div>
```

try this..

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer. :)

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'chassis'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'chassis',
    array('saloon' => 'saloon', 'station wagon' => 'station wagon', ),
    array('class'=>'form-control','empty' => 'Select one of the following...')
); 
?>
```